# DBVisualizer background colour

Tags: dbvisualizer

I have DB Visualizer 9.5.7 on Windows 10 64-bit, using Java 1.8.
I am not able to change the 'Normal' Background Color from the default White to another colour such as Grey (for example).
I am using the Free version. 
Should this work?
Thanks!

Comment: Dark Theme on Free version? @mlh351

Answer (score 0):

no this will not work, you need the premium version to do this.

https://www.dbvis.com/features/tour/connection-management/

under "Borders and Colors"